# Why all my spot requests are cancelling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have limited knowledge about spot pricing on AWS ec2 instances. I tried to make spot requests on p2.x instances on amazon. I tried it on Ohio & North Virginia regions. In both of them, my requests are cancelled instantaneously. In the past, there was no such problem and I applied the same procedure as I did in my previous attempts. What could be the problem ? I believe its about the maximum price policy but as I said it wasn't problem before and I don't know why it is now.

Comment: Which [Spot Bid Status](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-bid-status.html) are you seeing?